# Is the Causal Set Theory a QFT of gravity?

Tags: quantum-gravity

It's hard for me to tell if the Causal set theory is a quantum field theory of QG. There really isn't that much information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Causal set theory is an approach to quantum gravity which models events on 4 dimensional space time manifolds as points in partially ordered sets where the relation is causality in the sense of events having happened before or after others in time. I suggest checking out [this living review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11544) for a foray into the subject.

Whilst the subject is still young within the area of matter fields, path integral approaches have been explored extensively.